# Access Various pages of Website using Perl

Tags: perl

I need to navigate websites and perform various actions like logging in, browse to a specific page, fill out forms, extract certain text and corresponding js in respective files automatically.

For an example, I have to logged in one site and then access controls in navigated pages etc.
Some controls are controlled by javascript too,

By using WWW::Mechanize module I am unable to access javascript in a navigated page.

### Workflow:

Login page->Navigated_html_page->event->JsFunction->Loadothercontrols->Upload File->Submit action.

Can anyone suggest solutions for this?

Comment: Topic was discussed already very often. [Search for mechanize javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mechanize+javascript), relevant: <http://stackoverflow.com/q/857515> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/2655034> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/2703902> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/3769015> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/3900979> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/4767562> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/5342685> And these are just from the first result page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either reverse engineer the JS and do what it does in your Perl, or use something like [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aScripter) with the JavaScript or Ajax plugin.