# Login to a website using perl

Tags: perl, web

I am trying to login to a website using perl. I have tried all the options - LWP::Mechanize, LWP::UserAgent, etc. but still have not been able to login successfully. I get a response code of 200 which means successful but how will i move on to the next page? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186258/access-various-pages-of-website-using-perl.

Comment: There could be many things going on. You'll have to show a lot more than you have.

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong with your code if you show us no code. We can't read your mind.  Also, the package is WWW::Mechanize, not LWP::Mechanize.  Have you read the Mechanize FAQ?  Have you seen the first question that says that Mechanize does not handle JavaScript?  Could the page that you're logging into require JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using cookies with LWP

```
$ua->cookie_jar({ file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt" });
```

after the login just have the $ua request the next page.

If the login redacts you to another page and you want to get that then use

```
$ua->requests_redirectable
```

For more info check out the docs at
http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

Comment: here's the code i am using

$url = 'http://www.optionslam.com/index.html';
$username = 'abc';
$password = 'def';

$browser = LWP::UserAgent->new('Mozilla');
$browser->credentials("www.optionslam.com:80","realm-name",$username=>$password);
$response=$browser->get($url);
$code=$response->code;
#print $code;
if ($code = 200) {
 $content = $browser->get ("http://www.optionslam.com/myaccount.html");
 $content1 = $response->content;
 print $content1;


$content1 should contain the logged in page, but the source code does not show the details of the user name and password.am i doing something wrong?