# How can I run a Javascript of a web page in Perl?

Tags: javascript, perl, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use Perl to grab text from a web page that is dynamically generated with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655034/how-can-i-use-perl-to-grab-text-from-a-web-page-that-is-dynamically-generated-wi)

I am interested in learning Perl and just started to write a web crawler in Perl. On the page that I crawled, there is a Javascript for giving vote to the page. It shows the vote of the current page, only if I click the voting stars. So during the crawling, I need to run the Javascript and learn the current voting of the page.

Do you have any suggestions or examples?

Thanks..

Comment: Topic was discussed already very often. Search for perl javascript, relevant: <http://stackoverflow.com/q/857515> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/2655034> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/2703902> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/3769015> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/3900979> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/4767562> <http://stackoverflow.com/q/5342685> And these are just from the first result page. Mech FAQ: [Which modules work like Mechanize and have JavaScript support?](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#Which-modules-work-like-Mechanize-and-have-JavaScript-support-)

Comment: Submitting fake votes in order to get the data strikes me as being an exceptionally bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use module [WWW::Scripter](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aScripter) with [WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aScripter%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aJavaScript).

**Synopsis:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Scripter;

$w = new WWW::Scripter;
$w->use_plugin('JavaScript');  # packaged separately
$w->get('http://some.site.com/that/relies/on/javascript');
$w->eval(' alert("Hello from JavaScript") ');
$w->document->getElementsByTagName('div')->[0]->....
$w->content; # returns the HTML content, possibly modified by scripts
```

Answer (score 2):

Using perl to drive an actual browser is one option (e.g. [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox), [WWW::Selenium](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aSelenium), etc.).  To actually run javascript in perl, try [WWW::Scripter](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aScripter) with [WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aScripter%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aJavaScript).