# How I get ajax view source result?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, perl, dom

I want to get the result from websites that use ajax, when I save the view source the ajax details don't appear, but when i use firebug I can see the source. Is there a way to get this source to string at c# or Perl? Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I also have the hunch this is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). gil yossef, what do you want to accomplish with the generated source?

Comment: i want to analyse dynamic details, like stocks values from websites

Comment: Then that topic was discussed already very often, relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9559927 http://stackoverflow.com/q/857515 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2655034 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2703902 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3769015 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3900979 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4767562 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5342685 [Mech FAQ](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX use a remote call over http to update the HTML interface, so you need to find out the URL that the AJAX execution is calling. With the proper URL and params, you can do a LWP::UserAgent call and parse the response content.